# Remove default schema 'dbo' when generating linq to sql queries

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle, linq, entity-framework

Hi i am facnig one problem, I am working on a project in that we are using Entity Framework 5 to connect to sql as well as for oracle. for sql it works fine but for oracle i need to remove the schema name for that what i did is in the Table Attibute of the model i passed empty/null and even in the OnModelCreating method of dbcontext method i passed empty/null value to the schema. but the queries generated through linq are appending dbo schema as the default schema. is there any way to avoid entity framework from attaching 'dbo' as the schema?

Comment: What does your connection string look like for your Oracle connection? You could set a default schema for a user/login on your Oracle db and then set a connection string to that user which should then work as you need.

Comment: i know in oracle username serves as the schema name but i don't want that schema name to be attached by the entity framework

Comment: Can you create aliases for the schema

Comment: its a product database in that they have created the synonyms with by the table name without schema

Answer (score 0):

If you could upgrade to EF6. You can try intercepting all command text and removing all `[dbo]` text.

- Create a class that is derived from [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception).
- Register the interceptor `DbInterception.Add(new NoSechemaInterceptor());`
- Then in `NonQueryExecuting`, `ReaderExecuting` and `ScalarExecuting` method, add following code:

  `command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("[dbo].", string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try overriding the default schema in OnModelCreating event of your DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   // empty schema
   modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
}
```